# How to insert image source into a hidden input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

How can I get the hidden input value to be the image source?

I'm trying to send the source of the image displayed in the hidden value so that it can be sent to a database.

This is the current code I'm working on.

```html
<form class="form" action="LargeSymbol.php?submit=true" method="post">
    <img id="enlargedSymbol" type="text" size="60" name="pathOfSymbol" src='' /><br />

    <script>
        var querySrc = URI(window.location.href).search(true).src;
        $("#enlargedSymbol").attr("src", querySrc);
    </script>

    <input class="inputBox" type="hidden" name="pathOfSymbol" id="pathOfSymbol" value="src=''"/> 
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

    <input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="add()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the URL of the image already available in the `querySrc` variable, so you just need to select the hidden input and set it's `val()`. Try this:

```
var querySrc = URI(window.location.href).search(true).src;
$("#enlargedSymbol").prop("src", querySrc);
$('#pathOfSymbol').val(querySrc);
```